# NVD3 Stacked Area Chart - how to set tick values / domain AFTER instantiation?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, nvd3.js

How can I set tickValues/yDomain values **after** my stackedArea Chart initializes?

I can set the yDomain on initialization and the view will update:

```
 let chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                    .options(chartOptions)
                    .x(d => d.x)
                    .y(d => d.y)
                    .yDomain([0,1])
```

But only the model will update if I try to manipulate values after initialization:

```
 let chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                        .options(chartOptions)
                        .x(d => d.x)
                        .y(d => d.y);

chart.yDomain([-5,5]);
chart.yAxis.tickValues([-5, 1, 5]);

console.log(chart.yDomain) => [-5,5]
console.log(chart.yAxis.tickValues() => [-5, 1, 5]
//chart still has default yDomain and yTickValues, despite above console output.
```

How come?

---

*I want to set tick values/yDomain after instantiation because NVD3 mutates that values of my chart series in order to "stack" them. So I don't know what my domain will be until it's already been drawn.

Comment: I don't get it. In the second snippet you set the domain as well as the tick values and the exact same values are logged afterwards. So, what is your problem actually?

Comment: @altocumulus my problem is that the view does not display these new domain/tick values. it seems the model alone has changed.

Comment: is it possible to put a jsfiddle with test data showing your problem?